# Multiple Select for Edit User Wtih CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have table

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>userid</th>
            <th>image</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>family</th>
            <th>level</th>
            <th>fild</th>
            <th>operation</th>
            <th>up to next level</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in StudentFunc.ShowAllStudents(Model.Class))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.studentid</td>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/Image/StudentImage/@item.studntimage" width="60" height="60"/>
                </td>
                <td>@item.studentname</td>
                <td>@item.studentfamily</td>
                <td>@item.studentpayename</td>
                <td>@item.studentreshtename</td>
                <td>
                    <a onclick="Edit()" class="btn btn-primary click" href="@Url.Action("InsertScore", "Home", new {payeid = @item.PayeID, reshteid = @item.ReshteID, studentiD = @item.studentid, MostamarID = @StudentFunc.ShowStudents(item.studentid).MostamarID})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"><span style="font-family: 'B Titr'; margin-right: 10px;">ثبت نمره</span></span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("ListofScore", "Home", new {studentid = @item.studentid})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"><span style="font-family: 'B Titr'; margin-right: 10px;">لیست نمرات</span></span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("AddAbsent", "Home", new {studentid = @item.studentid})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"><span style="font-family: 'B Titr'; margin-right: 10px;"> ثبت غیبت</span></span></a>

                </td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBox("Pass", false)</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

in table I put a checkbox for select user for update level. Now how do I find what students selected and and how to send information about them to action?

Comment: Instead of giving a negative score Please guide me

Comment: What are your attempting to do here? - you generating checkboxes (form controls) and do not even have a form - all you have a links. And what controller method are you wanting to call? Apart for the invalid html your generating, all your checkboxes would be just sending either `true` or `false` which would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put your code in a form and replace

```
@Html.CheckBox("Pass", false) 
//with something like 
@Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item.Pass)
```

and submit the form (you should be able to do this).

Or you can keep a list with student ids in javascript (add/remove a student id on check/uncheck) and send that list to server with an ajax call.

These are just some hints, you will have to try to write this code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're iterating through the students the render the checkbox, I would suggest something like creating the checkboxes with a customer name that contains the student ID.

Replace

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("Pass", false)</td>
```

with something like

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("Pass_" + item.studentid)</td>
```

Now, in the controller action wherever you're posting these to, the Form Collection will contain all the selected checkbox names, and you can parse each one for "`Pass_{StudentId}`" to figure out which students were selected.

Comment: @Grham my question have tow part . how send to action all user of selected?